# Display Product Reviews by default

Tags: magento2, jquery, product-review

On Product Page I want to display the reviews related to product. Right now they are displayed on click function. This are the functions through which reviews are displayed.

```
 define([
'jquery'
 ], function ($) {
'use strict';

function processReviews(url, fromPages) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        cache: true,
        dataType: 'html',
        showLoader: false,
        loaderContext: $('.product.data.items')
    }).done(function (data) {
        $('#product-review-container').html(data);
        $('[data-role="product-review"] .pages a').each(function (index, element) {
            $(element).click(function (event) { //eslint-disable-line max-nested-callbacks
                processReviews($(element).attr('href'), true);
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    }).complete(function () {
        if (fromPages == true) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#reviews').offset().top - 50
            }, 300);
        }
    });
}

return function (config) {
    var reviewTab = $(config.reviewsTabSelector),
        requiredReviewTabRole = 'tab';

    if (reviewTab.attr('role') === requiredReviewTabRole && reviewTab.hasClass('opened')) {
        processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
    } else {
        reviewTab.one('beforeOpen', function () {
            processReviews(config.productReviewUrl);
        });
    }

    $(function () {
        $('.product-info-main .reviews-actions a').click(function (event) {
            var anchor;

            event.preventDefault();
            anchor = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/, '');
            $('.product.data.items [data-role="content"]').each(function (index) { //eslint-disable-line
                if (this.id == 'reviews') { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                    $('.product.data.items').tabs('activate', index);
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#' + anchor).offset().top - 120
                    }, 300);
                }
            });
        });
        
    });
};
```

});

Comment: What is this file name and location ? Are you getting this "dsads" in alert ?

Answer (score 1):

We can force the code to trigger the click by adding this code

```
$("document").ready(function() {
    $(".product-info-main .reviews-actions a").trigger('click');
});
```

And also you may remove the animate to scrollbar

```
   $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#' + anchor).offset().top - 120
                    }, 300);
```

Comment: tried but not working

Comment: My solution was not just copy paste, please tell me what error you getting in your console. May be you need setTimeout please  check this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060019/how-to-trigger-click-on-page-load